# How can I make part of regex optional?

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following regex that matches a string with a semicolon at the end:

```
\".+\";
```

It will match any string except an empty one, like the one below:

```
"";
```

I tried using this:

```
\".+?\";
```

But that didn't work.

My question is, how can I make the `.+` part of the, optional, so the user doesn't have to put any characters in the string?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To make the `.+` optional, you could do:

```
\"(?:.+)?\";
```

`(?:..)` is called a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). It only does the matching operation and it won't capture anything. Adding `?` after the non-capturing group makes the whole non-capturing group optional.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
\".*?\";
```

`.*` would match any character zero or more times greedily. Adding `?` after the `*` forces the regex engine to do a shortest possible match.

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning what the `?:` in the group is for and why it may (or may not) be necessary.

Comment: I am confused why not use grouping like this `\"(?:.+)?\";` and use the entire match?