# Dot character with literal matching

Tags: regex

I have a regex like following:

```
random(\.test\.)?.\s*.*
```

which matches `random.test.asd` and `random.asda`. I wanted to use `\.` so that word `test` may or may not be present in the text. But adding

```
random(\.test\.)?\.\s*.*
```

Just breaks the whole regex.

Comment: "so that word test may or may not be present in the text. ": Should it be "so that it only matches a literal dot"?

Comment: The word "test" is already optional in your original regex. Do you mean you want to make "test" optional, but still require a dot before the \s*.* part? If so just move the \. out like follows: `random(\.test)?\.\s*.*`

Comment: Both your patterns match, see https://regex101.com/r/55mFju/1 and https://regex101.com/r/QzxX8a/1 What do you mean by `Just breaks the whole regex`?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you're trying to write an expression, a bit similar to:

```
^random(?:\.test)?\.[^.\r\n]*$
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FT2cm4/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/FT2cm4/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

It is clear you are trying to [make a part of regex optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161320/how-can-i-make-part-of-regex-optional), but the problem is you have already had a bit wrong pattern. The `random(\.test\.)?.\s*.*` pattern matches any 1 char (other than a line break char) after `random` or `random.test.`, i.e. it is required. The rest of the pattern - 0+ whitespace and then any 0+ non-linebreak chars - does not even need to match. Once you escape the unescaped `.` you will be able to match strings like `random.test..some-th ing` or `random.some-th ing`, but not `random.test.something`.

**You should move the grouping boundaries**:

```
random(?:\.test)?\.\s*.*
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hEsvNg/1). **Details**

- `random` - a literal string
- `(?:\.test)?` - an optional `.test` substring (a non-capturing group with `?` quantifier after it matches a sequence of patterns optionally)
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=random(%3F%3A%5C.test)%3F%5C.%5Cs*.*):

[image]