# Regular Expression in Perl with different logic for same constraints

Tags: regex, perl, logic

I want to prepare a **regex in Perl** which can accept input only in the following 2 formats:

1) Containing one or more alphabets followed by a hyphen and again followed by one or more digits.
Example: ABC-111, X-1234, XYZ-2

2) Containing only digits. 
Example: 12445, 900, 1

I tried the expression `=~ /^[A-Z]+-\d+$|^\d+$/`
What this does is that it checks separately for the above two cases. This works fine.

However it will be a lot easier if I used the logic :
Check if zero or one occurence of [one or more alphabets are followed by a single hyphen] followed by one or more digits
Any possible regex for the above mentioned logic?
What I think it should be is `=~ /^([A-Z]+-)*\d+$/` . Unfortunately it does not work. Could anyone please suggest a possible solution with the above logic?

Comment: The 2nd pattern would also accept `ABC-DEF-123`.

Comment: True, use `/^(?:[A-Z]+-)?\d+$/`

Comment: Do you mean like `^(?:[A-Z]+-)?\d+$` Your pattern works for the example data https://regex101.com/r/6sHP7I/1 only the repetition is 0 or more times and you are repeating a capturing group which could be non capturing.

Comment: @collapsar change it to zero or one occurence

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. It is working. Could you please explain this?

Comment: @Thefourthbird then how do I restrict this capturing group? If I use {0,1} instead of *?

Comment: You could use both `?` or `{0,1}`

Comment: The explanation is available in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26161358/3832970).