# javascript regex data until new line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to remove all sentences if they start with particular character until break line.
So far I created something like this but it removes only these particular characters instead of whole line. I'm not good with regex expressions so would be grateful if someone could throw some hint

---

From: ABC, DEF <abc.l@def.com [mailto:abc.l@def.com]>

Upcoming Events:

Hello hello

Sent: Thursday, February 28, 20117:22 PM

---

```
var cleanup = msg.replace(/From.|Sent.|To.|Cc.*\n/g, "");
```

current output:

ABC, DEF <abc.l@def.com [mailto:abc.l@def.com]>

Upcoming Out of Office:

Hello hello

Thursday, July 29, 2021 7:48 PM

---

expected output:

Upcoming Out of Office:
Hello hello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
text = text.replace(/^\s*(?:From|Sent|To|Cc)\b.*[\r\n]*\s*/gm)
```

Or, if you need to also remove empty lines:

```js
text = text.replace(/^(?:\s*(?:From|Sent|To|Cc)\b.*)?[\r\n]*\s*/gm)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/cQ7RFz/3) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/cQ7RFz/4). *Details*:

- `^` - start of a line (`m` flag allows that)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:From|Sent|To|Cc)` - any of the alternatives
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or/and LF chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.

In the second regex, the `\s*(?:From|Sent|To|Cc)\b.*` part is [made optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161320/how-can-i-make-part-of-regex-optional) so that any libe breaks right after the beginning of a line could get consumed.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "From: ABC, DEF <abc.l@def.com [mailto:abc.l@def.com]>\n\nUpcoming Events:\n\nHello hello\n\nSent: Thursday, February 28, 20117:22 PM";
const rx = /^(?:\s*(?:From|Sent|To|Cc)\b.*)?[\r\n]*\s*/gm;
console.log(text.replace(rx, ""));
```