# Why does this regex not match my groups in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following complete code example

```
import re

examples = [
    "D1",       # expected: ('1')
    "D1sjdgf",  # ('1')
    "D1.2",     # ('1', '2')
    "D1.2.3",   # ('1', '2', '3')
    "D3.10.3x", # ('3', '10', '3')
    "D3.10.11"  # ('3', '10', '11')
]

for s in examples:
    result = re.search(r'^D(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)))', s)
    print(s, result.groups())
```

where I want to match the 1, 2 or 3 numbers in the expression always starting with the letter "D". It could be 1 of them, or 2, or three. I am not interested in anything after the last digit.

I would expect that my regex would match e.g. `D3.10.3x` and return `('3','10','3')`, but instead returns only  `('3',)`. I do not understand why.

`^D(\d+\)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)))`

- `^D` matches "D" at the start
- `\d` matches the first one-digit number inside a group.
- `(?:` starts a non-matching group. I do  not want to get this group back.
- `\.` A literal point
- `(\d+)` A group of one or more numbers I want to "catch"

I also do not know what a "non-capturing" group means in that context as for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions).

Comment: `[\.(\d+)+]` is a character class that has no group, ``[\.(\d+)+]`` = ``[.)(+\d]``. It should be `(?:\.(\d+))?`, i.e. you must use an optional non-capturing group instead of a character class.

Comment: question updated

Comment: "is a character class that has no group" not sure what you mean

Comment: Try `^D(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?)?`

Comment: The other answers do not seem to answer my question.

Comment: [They work well](https://regex101.com/r/odiCBf/1). You confused a character class for an optional non-capturing group.

Comment: Ok I removed the rectangular brackets. Still does not work. Even with non-capturing groups. Should I create a new question what will get closed without valid reason?

Comment: You did not use the [optional groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633334/regex-optional-group) that was linked to as close reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make part of regex optional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161320/how-can-i-make-part-of-regex-optional)

Comment: No, that's not correct dupe. None of the answers address this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex solution with a start anchor and 2 capture groups inside the nested optional capture groups:

```py
^D(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/u1qvY5/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^`: Start
- `D`: Match letter `D`
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `(?:`: Start outer non-capture group

  - `\.`: Match a dot
  - `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #2
  - `(?:`: Start inner non-capture group

    - `\.`: Match a dot
    - `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #3
  - `)?`: End inner *optional* non-capture group
- `)?`: End outer *optional* non-capture group

[**Code Demo:**](https://ideone.com/ck2PIP)

```py
import re

examples = [
    "D1",       # expected: ('1')
    "D1sjdgf",  # ('1')
    "D1.2",     # ('1', '2')
    "D1.2.3",   # ('1', '2', '3')
    "D3.10.3x", # ('3', '10', '3')
    "D3.10.11"  # ('3', '10', '11')
]

rx = re.compile(r'^D(\d+)(?:\.(\d+)(?:\.(\d+))?)?')

for s in examples:
    result = rx.search(s)
    print(s, result.groups())
```

**Output:**

```py
D1 ('1', None, None)
D1sjdgf ('1', None, None)
D1.2 ('1', '2', None)
D1.2.3 ('1', '2', '3')
D3.10.3x ('3', '10', '3')
D3.10.11 ('3', '10', '11')
```

Comment: Sorry, I used your suggestion in some other regex. Seems to work. And maybe I even understand it a bit how it works. Thanks!